# Independent (isolated) installation of python

Tags: linux, python, make

We've got a server (CentOS 3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64) with Python 2.7 as the system Python.

It doesn't have installed pip nor venv nor virtualenv... so I understand that I can not even create virtual environments, and in any case I need a more modern Python. I'm also not root.

I want to install a more modern Python (3.10) in my home directory in the most isolated possible way. After looking for information, what I have already done is:

```
cd ~
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.2/Python-3.10.2.tgz
tar -xvzf Python-3.10.2.tgz
mkdir opt
cd Python-3.10.2
```

And my next steps were:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/opt/python-3.10.2
make
make install
```

My idea is using this isolated installation to create environments for the different projects I want to make.

I don't know Linux up to the point of being sure that this is not going to interfere with the Python system in any way.

I don't know if that depends on the program being installed or if that way of installing programs guarantees that the program doesn't modify the system (outside of my home directory, at least)

What I expect is to modify files only inside my home directory and nothing else

Can anybody, please, confirm?

Thanks

Comment: You're reinventing pyenv, seems like.

Comment: I didn't know about pyenv, but it does seem that I'm trying a similar thing. The problem is that I seem to be out of luck, since gcc is not installed in my system, and so I cann't compile Python, nor probably pyenv. Is there any possibility I may try?